# Add filter conditionally to a page

Tags: filters, conditional-content

I am using a filter to change a label on a particular page and set the rest the same.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'themeprefix_cart_button_text' ); 
 //Add New Pay Button Text
function themeprefix_cart_button_text() {
    if(is_page(3601)) :
 return __( 'Buy Now', 'woocommerce' );
    else:
return __( 'Add To Cart', 'woocommerce' );
    endif;
}
```

But not working - anything wrong with the conditional code?

Comment: The code is functionally fine, but are you sure page `3601` is correct, and that the product is a single product? Also `is_page()` will be checking the ID of the page you're viewing, not the ID of the product whose text you're changing. Is that your intention?

Comment: Yes definitely a page, id is correct, single product brought in via shortcode